# Is there a way to distinguish error and empty array returned from subroutine when it is called in list context?

Tags: perl

I have script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

sub t0 {
    return;     # We return nothing for ERROR
}

sub t1 {
    @z =  ();
    return @z;  # We return array (which maybe empty) for no ERROR
}
```

In scalar context I can distinguish error and OK status:

```
my $x1 =  t0();  # undef
my $x2 =  t1();  # 0
```

Is there a way to distinguish error and empty array returned from subroutine when it is called in list context?

```
my @x1 =  t0();  # empty list
my @x2 =  t1();  # empty list
```

I am feeling that I need "0E0" (Zero but TRUE) but for list context.

Comment: There's no way to distinguish returning 0 scalars using `return;` from returning 0 scalars using `return @z;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A way to distingish between the empty list and an error in this case would be to return an array reference, e.g.

```
sub t0 {
    return undef;     # We return undef for ERROR
}

sub t1 {
    @z =  ();
    return \@z;  # We return array (which maybe empty) for no ERROR
}
```

So basically the functions do not behave differently in list context. They always return a single scalar, which may be `undef`, which indicates an error, or return a reference to an array.

Answer (score 4):

No.

Return an array reference if successful (which the caller will have to dereference) and undef on failure.

Or throw an exception on failure (which the calling code could catch).

Answer (score 1):

In list context a sub *will return a list*, even if it only has one element which is `undef`. If you must return data in a flat list – if it is not feasible to change the callers, say in a large codebase -- you can `die` on error and `eval` somewhere at a top level. (As `die` is an exception it "bubbles.")

The other option for the flat list is rather unappealing, and it still requires changes to callers. You can return an empty list or an `undef` and then test accordingly -- but see the comment below.

```
sub test {  
    # set @z (but not with undef!), $error
    return undef if $error;
    return @z;
}

my @ret = test();

if (not @ret) {
    # empty list
} 
else {
    foreach my $elem (@ret) {
        if (not defined $elem) {
            warn "Undefined";
            last
        }
        # ...
    }
}
```

However, as pointed out by [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami), if `@z` gets assigned an `undef` legitimately (without error), for example a variable that happens to be undefined, this code can't tell the difference.  So the function would have to be changed further to deal with that.